# windows PowerShell ISE multi scripts (remove - zip - rename)

Tags: module, compression, file-rename, powershell-ise

I would like delete a folder named pdf3.wgt after that .zip content of a folder (where was this pdf3.wgt) and finaly rename it in pdf3.wgt, (with windows PowerShell ISE).

**prerequisite: C:\wamp64\www\pdf3\pdf3.wgt file exist**

When i run (f5) this scripts created by the  PowerShell ISE with module Compress-Archive and Rename-Item:

`Remove-Item -Path C:\wamp64\www\pdf3\pdf3.wgt
PS C:\Users\tonys> Compress-Archive -DestinationPath C:\wamp64\www\pdf3\pdf3.zip -Path C:\wamp64\www\pdf3
PS C:\Users\tonys> Rename-Item -NewName pdf3.wgt -Path C:\wamp64\www\pdf3\pdf3.zip`

**in  PowerShell ISE on windows 10 i got this error:**

`PS C:\Users\tonys> rmdir C:\wamp64\www\pdf3\pdf3.wgt

PS C:\Users\tonys> Compress-Archive -DestinationPath C:\wamp64\www\pdf3\pdf3.zip -Path C:\wamp64\www\pdf3

PS C:\Users\tonys> Rename-Item -NewName pdf3.wgt -Path C:\wamp64\www\pdf3\pdf3.zip

Get-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Compress-Archive'.

At line:2 char:1
+ PS C:\Users\tonys> Compress-Archive -DestinationPath C:\wamp64\www\pd ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand

Get-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Rename-Item'.
At line:3 char:1
+ PS C:\Users\tonys> Rename-Item -NewName pdf3.wgt -Path C:\wamp64\www\ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand`

**Could someone tell me why use module proposed by powershell  d'ont work ?
adn why he said to me '**

> A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument ?

'
++

Comment: Please include the complete script to show a re-create. The error is coming from `Get-Process` but there is no call (or use of an alias) to that cmdlet in your quoted code. (Are you trying to use a `process` block in a script or function?)

Comment: Hi Richard, I copy those scripts from the modules created and i use in the 'script pane'   -1) Remove-Item -Path C:\wamp64\www\pdf3\pdf3.wgt  -2) Compress-Archive -DestinationPath C:\wamp64\www\pdf3\pdf3.zip -Path C:\wamp64\www\pdf3 -CompressionLevel Optimal -Debug  -3) Rename-Item -NewName pdf3.wgt -Path C:\wamp64\www\pdf3\pdf3.zip

Comment: Please add refinements to the question: too hard to read in comments. And there is nothing there that would trigger `Get-Process`.

Comment: Ok many thanks bu i found the error, just removed extra portion at start line "PS C:\Users\tonys>" from each command. thanks tried help me;

Comment: Result summarised in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a script by copying from an interactive session *do not include the command prompt*.

> ```
> PS C:\Users\tonys> Compress-Archive -DestinationPath C:\wamp64\www\pdf3\pdf3.zip -Path C:\wamp64\www\pdf3
> ```

`PS` is an alias for `Get-Process` and its arguments bare no resemblance to the rest of the line.